# How to dispatch an action with current value of state?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an angular component showing items in a list. Each itemn can be selected and the ids of the selected items will be stored in the state. So my state object looks like this f.e.:

```
{ items: Item[]; selected: string[] }
```

Now I got an action called `DeleteSelectedAction` that gets `selected` as payload. This action will call some WebAPI using an effect and so on.

Now I found two ways how I could do this.

**First:** Select `selected` from store and subscribe to it and pass the value with the action

```
store.select(fromItems.getSelected).subscribe(ids => {
    this.selected = ids; 
});
...
store.dispatch(new itemActions.DeleteSelectedAction(this.selected);
```

**Second:** Pass no value to action but fetch the `selected` in effect

```
store.dispatch(new itemActions.DeleteSelectedAction());

// in effect
@Effect()
delete$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(fromItems.DELETE)
  .withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromItems.getSelected)
  .switchMap([action, selected] => {
    return this.service.delete(selected)
      .map(new itemActions.DeleteSuccessAction())
      .catch(err => Observable.of(new itemActions.DeleteFailAction(err));
  });
```

I don't like the first way because I need to use a subscription and need to unsubscribe properly. The second way is ok but only when the action has side effects.
So now I'm looking for a third way. In my head this way looks like the following:

```
store.dispatchWithLatestFrom(
  fromItems.getSelected,
  (selected) => new itemActions.DeleteSelectedAction(selected));
```

How could I get something like that with rxjs operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach should work just fine even if the action has no side effects. using an `@Effect` to transform an action without performing a side effect is a perfectly legitimate use of the library. See the section on Content Enrichers [here](https://blog.nrwl.io/ngrx-patterns-and-techniques-f46126e2b1e5). In that case, I'd definitely call the action something like `DELETE_SELECTED` rather than just `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

What we are using is

```
store.select(fromItems.getSelected).take(1).subscribe(ids => 
    store.dispatch(new itemActions.DeleteSelectedAction(ids))
```

Yes, instead of dispatching it inside the subscribe you could also assign it to a field, ... but this is the shortest way which I've found to work for us quite well.