# What is the correct way to read from NgRx store using selector in an angular service and use the value to call another function?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an NgRx selector defined like this

```
selectedRows = createSelector(
    someState,
    state => state[fromDataSource.someSliceKey].selectedRows);
```

Whenever some items are selected on a component (UI), `selectedRows` gets updated with latest selected items.
Now there is another button on another component which calls an angular service to perform some operation which eventually calls bunch of an external APIs. I would like to read the values stored in `selectedRows` using the above defined selector on the angular service and make those API calls.

What is the correct way to do this?

One of the approach I am considering is to subscribe to the selector something like this:

```
const selectedRows$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(fromSelectors.selectedRows)
  ).subscribe(data => {
  // call other functions and dispatch actions to call external API
});
```

Since I am calling subscribe here how do I unsubscribe? Is there way to do this without having to call subscribe?

Update: Found another similar question - [How to dispatch an action with current value of state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108022/how-to-dispatch-an-action-with-current-value-of-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a good use case for [NgRx Effects](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects):

```js
myEffects$ = createEffect(
  () => actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actionDispatchedWhenButtonPressed)
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectedRows))),
    switchMap(([action, selectedRows]) => /* ...API calls... */)
  )
)
```

Comment: I did come across this post which talked about using the `withLatestFrom`, let me try it: https://medium.com/@viestursv/how-to-get-store-state-in-ngrx-effect-fab9e9c8f087

Comment: [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom#toc-withlatestfrom-the-master-slave-operator) is also a great article that explains `withLatestFrom`, as well as other combination operators: `zip`, `combineLatest` and `forkJoin`

Comment: since I have `selectedRows` I iterated on it in the `swithMap` above and triggered an action each which call external API and added `return EMPTY;` on the `switchMap` after the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

NgRx is like a wrapper around RxJS, so all the Rxjs operators will work with NgRx smoothly

if you call not single external API but many then it's okay just dont' forget to use `take(1)` operator otherwise the subscription will be called every time `selectRows` gets updated. but if you want to also return then [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) for that

```
    return this.store.pipe(select(fromSelectors.selectedRows),take(1))
.pipe(swichMap(()=>//your API call)
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `select` function's second argument: [source](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/store.ts#L133). It has to be either a props object(or a primitive variable) or another string in case the first argument was a string.

Comment: sorry type error, it should be inside the pipe function as second argument, updated the answer

Comment: good point, in my case I have multiple so `take(1)` is not necessary though.